# discord.py audio difference on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, discord.py

I've cloned my discord.py bot repo to my raspberrypi. I am not getting the same functionality that I get from my mac. Everything except the audio commands seem to be working. Is there a library that I need to install separate from the pip requirements?

pi info:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian


async def play_audio(self, ctx, clip):
    vc = await self.join(ctx)

    voice = get(ctx.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}/../audio/{clip}.mp3"))
    while voice.is_playing():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    await vc.disconnect()
```

Comment: Are there any errors? Can you write your current attempt?

Comment: @ParasolKirby No errors. The bot joins the channel and lights up for the duration of the audio then leaves as expected. It just doesn't actually play anything.